Low Resolution in Org Latex Preview
On a high res display the, preview produced by 'org-latex-preview' , i.e., 'C-c C-x C-l' is pretty low res and fuzzy compared to text.

I found this similar question and the suggested solution was to
(setq org-preview-latex-default-process 'dvisvgm) for Org version 9 or to (setq org-latex-create-formula-image-program 'dvisvgm) for previous versions.
I tried both and I get the following error
org-compile-file: File "/private/var/folders/ks/9_vxpf6n0xgfkcws9s73kqhh0000gn/T/orgtexXHIQBp.svg" wasn’t produced.  Please adjust ‘dvisvgm’ part of ‘org-preview-latex-process-alist’.
The value of org-preview-latex-process-alist is
((dvipng :programs
     ("latex" "dvipng")
     :description "dvi > png" :message "you need to install the programs: latex and dvipng." :image-input-type "dvi" :image-output-type "png" :image-size-adjust
     (1.0 . 1.0)
     :latex-compiler
     ("latex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
     :image-converter
     ("dvipng -D %D -T tight -o %O %f")
     :transparent-image-converter
     ("dvipng -D %D -T tight -bg Transparent -o %O %f"))
 (dvisvgm :programs
      ("latex" "dvisvgm")
      :description "dvi > svg" :message "you need to install the programs: latex and dvisvgm." :image-input-type "dvi" :image-output-type "svg" :image-size-adjust
      (1.7 . 1.5)
      :latex-compiler
      ("latex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
      :image-converter
      ("dvisvgm %f --no-fonts --exact-bbox --scale=%S --output=%O"))
 (imagemagick :programs
          ("latex" "convert")
          :description "pdf > png" :message "you need to install the programs: latex and imagemagick." :image-input-type "pdf" :image-output-type "png" :image-size-adjust
          (1.0 . 1.0)
          :latex-compiler
          ("pdflatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
          :image-converter
          ("convert -density %D -trim -antialias %f -quality 100 %O")))


With the following meaning for placeholders
Place-holders used by ‘:image-converter’ and ‘:latex-compiler’:
%f    input file name
%b    base name of input file
%o    base directory of input file
%O    absolute output file name
Place-holders only used by ‘:image-converter’:
%D    dpi, which is used to adjust image size by some processing commands.
%S    the image size scale ratio, which is used to adjust image size by some
processing commands.

I don't know know what to do from here, Can someone help make those previews crisp.
P.S. - I already tried changing scale in scale in org-format-latex-options but that just increases image size rather than quality.
I have found a few more similar questions as this.
Edit :
As suggested by @Tianshu Wang, I checked the output of the buffer *Org Preview Latex Output* and saw
warning: kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories: /opt/local/etc/texmf.
WARNING: none of the default map files could be found
pre-processing DVI file (format version 2)
WARNING: PostScript header file tex.pro not found
WARNING: PostScript header file texps.pro not found
WARNING: PostScript header file special.pro not found
WARNING: PostScript header file color.pro not found
PostScript error: undefined in TeXDict

So I think there is some issue with my dvisvgm install as I saw the same issue here.

Check the content of buffer *Org Preview LaTeX Output*

@TianshuWang Saw it and added that to edit.

There was an issue with my dvisvgm install. Basically, I am on a mac and I already had dvisvgm installed from MacPorts which was being used. I uninstalled that so that the TexLive version of dvisvgm would be used and voila, you have at beautiful, Crisp, Latex in Org. For reference I would add that config here
    (setq org-preview-latex-default-process 'dvisvgm) 
    ;; Or
    (setq org-latex-create-formula-image-program 'dvisvgm)
    ;; This one works in all versions of Org.

